# How to set cookies within Cypress testing?

Tags: cookies, e2e-testing, cypress

[image: Cypress Cookie Setting]

this example taken from the Cypress documentation won't work properly:

```
cy.getCookies().should('be.empty');
cy.setCookie('session_id', '189jd09sufh33aaiidhf99d09');
cy.getCookie('session_id').should('have.property', 'value', '189jd09sufh33aaiidhf99d09');
```

Every time I try to setCookie(), it appears to set it without issue but always returns this when I call getCookies():

```
$Chainer {chainerId: "chainer18", firstCall: false}
chainerId: "chainer18"
firstCall: false
__proto__: Object
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: i think the answer is in the documentation: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/getcookies.html#Examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was related to https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1321 and has been patched in v 3.1.2 of Cypress.  All is right with the world again.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cy.getCookies()` without arguments. That function returns array of cookies that you have. Than you can do:

```
cy.getCookies().should('have.length', 1).then((cookies) => {
  expect(cookies[0]).to.have.property('session_id', '189jd09sufh33aaiidhf99d09')
})
```