# Cypress - Accessing website after Oauth validation

Tags: oauth, cypress

I am trying to access the website (UI) after doing Oauth with API. This is what my code looks like.

```
**Command.js**

Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password) => {
    Cypress.log({
      name: 'loginViaOauth',
    });
        const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://IPaddress/API/oauth/token',

        "body":'blah blah'
      };
      cy.request(options)
  });
```

and calling it like

```
cy.login(myusername,mypassword)  // Success here
```

after this, say I want to access any other page of site so I am trying to use

```
cy.visit('/mypage')
```

but it seems like I have not logged in. 
Please anyone tell what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Are you adding token before executing visit?

Comment: How do you do cypress oauth1.0 authentication? Do you have some sample code to show me? I'm stuck on figuring out how to write it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the correct thing, just need to add below in actual code

```
cy.request('/Account/SignIn')
    .its('body')
    .then((body) => {
      const csrf = Cypress.$(body).find('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
      cy.login(myusername,mypassword,csrf)  /* This custom method is defined in support/command.js */
        .then((resp) => { 
          expect(resp.status).to.eq(200)
        })

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways cookies and token can implement. I would touch base with the developer and understand that.

```
cy.setCookie('auth_key', '123key')
```

Here is detail documentation from cypress.io

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/setcookie.html#Syntax

StackOverFlow similar discussion : [How to set cookies within Cypress testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050294/how-to-set-cookies-within-cypress-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Cypress will consider every test case as a new environment. As a result, if you want to keep some Auth info across your tests you will have to save and reload the info after and before each test. Here is an example:

```
/** Session Caching */

var localStorageCache = { 'userSettings' : null, ... }; // Define keys to save/load in between tests here.
var cookieCache = { 'jwtToken' : null, 'searchSessionID' : null, ... };


Cypress.Commands.add('saveBrowserSession', function(options = {}){
    _.forEach(_.keys(localStorageCache), function(storageKey){
        localStorageCache[storageKey] = localStorage.getItem(storageKey) || null;
    });
    _.forEach(_.keys(cookieCache), function(cookieKey){
        cookieCache[cookieKey] = cy.getCookie(cookieKey) || null;
    });
});

Cypress.Commands.add('loadBrowserSession', function(options = {}){
    _.forEach(_.keys(localStorageCache), function(storageKey){
        if (typeof localStorageCache[storageKey] === 'string'){
            localStorage.setItem(storageKey, localStorageCache[storageKey]);
        }
    });
    _.forEach(_.keys(cookieCache), function(cookieKey){
        if (typeof cookieCache[cookieKey] === 'string'){
            cy.setCookie(cookieKey, cookieCache[cookieKey]);
        }
    });
});

Cypress.Commands.add('clearBrowserSession', function(options = {}){
    _.forEach(_.keys(localStorageCache), function(storageKey){
        localStorageCache[storageKey] = null;
    });
    _.forEach(_.keys(cookieCache), function(cookieKey){
        cookieCache[cookieKey] = null;
    });
    cy.loadBrowserSession();
});
```

In your test:

```
before(function(){
    cy.clearBrowserSession();
});

beforeEach(function(){
    cy.loadBrowserSession();
});

afterEach(function(){
    cy.saveBrowserSession();
});

after(function(){
    // Probably unnecessary as Cypress cleans up between tests.
    cy.clearBrowserSession();
});
```

Cypress bug URL: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/747

Cypress UI testing good practices: [Cypress good practices](https://medium.com/@cbernardes/how-to-get-the-best-of-ui-test-automation-using-cypress-and-ci-continuous-integration-f9c5f056b364?source=friends_link&sk=49e3b6795e7ff889afc58a965d005917)