# In Cypress, how to setCookie before test?

Tags: javascript, cypress, autotest

How to resolve it?

> Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also
> invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.
>
> The command that returned the promise was:
>
> > cy.visit()
>
> The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:
>
> > cy.setCookie()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D49ul.png)

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import { internet, name } from "faker";
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";

const email = internet.exampleEmail();
const password = internet.password();
const first_name = name.firstName();
const last_name = name.lastName();

let user;

before(function registerUser() {
  cy.request("POST", "https://api.domain.io/api/users/", {
    first_name: first_name,
    last_name: last_name,
    email: email,
    password: password,
  })
    .its("body")
    .then((res) => {
      user = res;
    });
});


beforeEach(function setUser() {
  cy.visit("https://app.domain.io/projects/create", {
    onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
      cy.setCookie("token", user.token);
    },
  });
});

describe("JWT", () => {
  it("create project", () => {
    cy.get('[type="text"]').type("Autotest project");
    cy.get('[type="submit"]').click();
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set cookies within Cypress testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050294/how-to-set-cookies-within-cypress-testing)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve it this way:

```js
beforeEach(function setUser() {
  cy.setCookie("token", user.token);
  cy.visit("https://app.domain.io/projects/create");
});
```